# White pages while printing

Tags: google-sheets, printing

I've made a simple sheet to generate a random list of words to be printed. I don't know why but even if I've made the formula to check the number of words in column A of "lista" tab, on the print tab, it continue to generate white cells and so, when I press print, it want to print 22 pages (20 empty). Could you help me to limit this to just the pages needed to print the available words generated in the print tab?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jb66PhYPsegNJYpzwrYIArLp0vTBjMtaNOqNf-qSrdA/edit#gid=0

Comment: Add the formula to the question

Answer (score 0):

Delete the blank rows on your print page. Your data ends at row 71 but you have a bunch of blank rows underneath and you are wondering why it wants to print blank pages?

Comment: I know, and I've deleted them, but after few seconds they appear again even if I'm using a cell to count the number of items, that's why I'm asking...

Comment: @SimoneRosmarino give me the steps to make it appear, I deleted them, and they are not reappearing for me.

Comment: what did u deleted exactly? Cells or their content? Cos I wanna keep the cells but empty, and it should preview me to print only the area with text normally. For example, if I copy the pure text in a new sheet, it prompted to print exactly just it, but in the "print" tab, it ask me to print 22 pages (blank cells). I went to those went cell, hit backspace to delete, gsheet recognize them as empty but still wanna print 22 pages...I dont wanna delete the rows cos I wanna keep the grid formatted in my way for new data entries basically

Comment: @SimoneRosmarino I click on all the blank rows on the bottom and I right click and press delete rows.

Comment: But I wanna have that format for any new lines, how could I do it otherwise?

Comment: @SimoneRosmarino the new lines will automatically expand as needed.

Comment: you are right, but without the format (White vertical lines plus 2 thick black lines). I'd like to have that expanded as well...so I've setted it that way

Comment: @SimoneRosmarino when formatting is from top to bottom it continues to expand into new rows for me.